# Why isn't my html code outputting the variable's value when I use Flask to render a template?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a main.py file and a templates folder, inside of the templates folder I have math.html. It is just a basic html file. Inside the main.py, I am rendering the template which is called math.html. Note that I am using Flask.

This is my main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/math-game')
def game():  # This is the function which renders math.html
    num1 = random.randint(0, 100)
    num2 = random.randint(0, 100)

    return render_template('math.html', num1=num1, num2=num2)
```

Whereas in my math.html, I have the following code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Math Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Math Game</h1></center>

<h2>What is {{ num1 }} + {{ num2 }}?</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

When I check the output in my website, It just shows "What is {{ num1 }} + {{ num2 }}?". Why isn't it getting the values of num1 and num2 from main.py and displaying it here instead of just shows the above?

Please do help

Thanks

Comment: silly question but how do you run the app? Where do you check the page?

Comment: I use local host port 127... math.html

Comment: You didnt start the app? Something like python app.py? If you just look at the page without flask serving it, you will of course not see the rendered template.

Comment: Yes you should be running this with `flask run` and loading the URL `http://localhost:5000/math-game` in the browser.  Not opening the template file directly in your browser, which it sounds like you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this http://localhoat:5000/math-game

Do not open the math-game.html because this will load the .html.file and it will not read the {{  }}